# In WPF, how to Convert a D3DImage to Bitmap?

Tags: wpf, interop, bitmap

I'm trying to paste images from an external source (Paint.NET in my test), but it gives a D3DImage which I don't know how to convert to Bitmap.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

A `D3DImage`, although it is a strange beast, is an `ImageSource`, so you can use as the `Source` for an `Image` and an `Image` is a `Visual` so you can use `RenderTargetBitmap` on it.  There is sample code in the `RenderTargetBitmap` documentation that actually copies the bitmap from the `Visual` to another `Image` on same page:

- [RenderTargetBitmap Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx)

Comment: Disappointing.  It may require a little more manual labor.  Check out the D3DImage Walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656785.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I find weird all that stuff using the timer, so I'm gonna make a better question with a reward.

Comment: Good luck.  If you can provide a test case, people will work for the bounty.